# lintr is not working with sublime

Tags: sublime-text-3, lint

I have installed a SublimeLinter via package control, `lintr` is not available in package control, I have installed it via git. R is connected to sublime, package `lintr` was installed by `install.packages("lintr")`. But I get this error:

> No lint results.

Can someone please help me to configure `lintr` in Sublime?

Comment: So you did install SublimeLinter, but what about [SublimeLinter-contrib-lintr](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-lintr)? Is `lintr` in your PATH, does it work from your terminal?

Comment: I've added: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\library\lintr" to the PATH of the Enviroment variables in my computer. And lintr runs fine in R, with lintr::lint(Bad.R)